# How to get memory used by a particular code in python as well as memory available in our pc

Tags: python, windows, memory, memory-management, cpu

I want to know how much memory this code consumes . Also available memory in my pc using a python code. What has to be done?

Here is my code :

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import os
import glob
from natsort import natsorted
import datetime
import time
import shutil
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

def fast(path, thread_name):
if os.path.splitext(path)[1] == '.mp4':
    print("Start : " + str(thread_name) + "  -  " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))
    clip = (VideoFileClip(path).fx(vfx.speedx, 5))
    clip.to_videofile('G:/Ocsid Technologies/BUILDERS/Builder-1/Project-1/Converted Videos/' + 
    thread_name + '.mp4', codec='libx264')
    time.sleep(3)
    shutil.move(path, "G:/Ocsid Technologies/BUILDERS/Builder-1/Project-1/Original Videos/")
    print("End : " + str(thread_name) + "  -  " + str(datetime.datetime.now()))

with ThreadPoolExecutor(5) as pool:
      for i, filename in enumerate(glob.glob("G:/Ocsid Technologies/BUILDERS/Builder-1/Project-1/Raw 
 Videos/*.mp4"), 1):
    pool.submit(fast, filename, f"t{i}")
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use Visual Studio Code, you can add two interruption points (beginning and end of the code) and using the Diagnostic Tools window you can get this data.

[Diagnostic tools on Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxRMg.png)

[Diagnostic tools on Visual Studio Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uQddF.png)

Below a link (in Spanish) where it is explained

https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/profiling/memory-usage?view=vs-2022

I hope it helps

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can you elaborate?